# I'm getting a "AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'bot" error

Tags: python, discord.py

```
client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '>', help_command=None)
```

This is the code where I get the error from. Even if I have a bot.py in discord.ext.commands and I did import commands from discord.ext

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
```

Answer (score 4):

It's `Bot` with an uppercase **B**.

```py
commands.Bot(...)
```